# DuckDuckGo search returns 'List Index out of range'

Tags: python, duckduckgo-api

Here is my Duck Duck Go search script.

```
import duckduckgo
r = duckduckgo.query('DuckDuckGo')
print r.results[0].url
```

it returns; list index out of range. If i print r.results i get;

```
[<duckduckgo.Result object at 0x0000000002E98F60>]
```

But if i search for anything other than 'DuckDuckGo'. It returns an Empty value

```
[]
```

I havefollowed exactly what they did in the example code. 
https://github.com/mikejs/python-duckduckgo

Answer (score 4):

That is [documented behaviour](https://github.com/mikejs/python-duckduckgo). There are different result attributes.

Your first query returns a list of results.

```
r = duckduckgo.query('DuckDuckGo')
if r.type == 'answer':
    print r.results    # [<duckduckgo.Result object>]
```

Your other search returns a disambiguation and your results are in `r.related` not in `r.results`

```
r = duckduckgo.query('Python')
if r.type == 'disambiguation':
    print r.related    # [<duckduckgo.Result object>]
```

**Edit**: python-duckduckgo uses the [DuckDuckGo API](https://duckduckgo.com/api) which does not give you all the search result links

> Our Instant Answer API gives you free access to many of our instant
>   answers like: topic summaries (API example), categories (API example),
>   disambiguation (API example), !bang redirects (API example), and
>   definitions (API example).
>
> This API does not include all of our links, however. That is, it is
>   not a full search results API or a way to get DuckDuckGo results into
>   your applications beyond our instant answers. Because of the way we
>   generate our search results, we unfortunately do not have the rights
>   to fully syndicate our results. For the same reason, we cannot allow
>   framing our results without our branding. Please see our partnerships
>   page for more info on guidelines and getting in touch with us.

You can't do what you want to do using the DuckDuckGo API but a possible workaround has been posted on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923803/241866

Comment: Thanks. But when i search for Python using the second script i get a url http://duckduckgo.com/Colt_Python. This link has a link to other websites. How do i get the list of these websites. ed:- 'the wikipedia link of python'