# Global Python packages in Sublime Text plugin development

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

### 1. Summary

I don't find, how Sublime Text plugins developer can use Sublime Text find global Python packages, not Python packages of Sublime Text directory.

Sublime Text use own Python environment, not Python environment of machine. [**Developers needs `sys.path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15180938/5951529) for set not built-in Sublime Text Python packages.

Is any methods, that use global installed Python packages in Sublime Text plugins? For example, it would be nice, if someone tells me, how I can change my plugin — see 3.2 item of this question.

---

### 2. Disadvantages of using Sublime Text 3 environment

1. Sublime Text 3 Build 3126 use Python 3.3, but at the time of writing this question release Python 3.6 stable. Python 3.6 have more features.
2. Developers needs add and update third-party Python packages, even they installed for users. It spends a time of developers.
3. For developers there may be problems with dependencies of packages, see 6.2 item of this question.

---

### 3. Example

#### 1. Python code

For example, I wrote Python code — replace `Поиск Кристиниты` to `[**Поиск Кристиниты**](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io)`, where `https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io` — first link of DuckDuckGo query `Поиск Кристиниты`.

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from w3lib.url import safe_url_string


# ASCII link for solved encoding problems —
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/40654295/5951529
ascii_link = safe_url_string(
    u'http://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=' + 'Поиск Кристиниты',
    encoding="UTF-8")
print(ascii_link)
# SERP DuckDuckGo
serp = urllib.request.urlopen(ascii_link)
# Reading SERP
read_serp = serp.read()
# BeautifulSoup — https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923803/5951529
parsed = BeautifulSoup(read_serp, "lxml")
# Parsed first link
first_link = parsed.findAll(
    'div', {'class': re.compile('links_main*')})[0].a['href']
# Remove DuckDuckGo specific characters —
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/3942100/5951529
remove_duckduckgo_symbols = first_link.replace("/l/?kh=-1&uddg=", "")
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/32451970/5951529
final_link = (urllib.parse.unquote(remove_duckduckgo_symbols))
# Markdown link
markdown_link = '[' + 'Поиск Кристиниты' + ']' + \
    '(' + final_link + ')'

print(markdown_link)
```

If I run this file in terminal or SublimeREPL, I get in output:

```
[**Поиск Кристиниты**](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/)
```

#### 2. Sublime Text plugin

Now, based on this code, I wrote Sublime Text plugin for replace `example text` to `[**example text**](http://<first link for DuckDuckGo query “example link”>)`:

```python
import re
import urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from w3lib.url import safe_url_string

import sublime_plugin


class KristinitaLuckyLinkCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):
        # Get selection text
        print('KristinitaLuckyLink called')
        select = self.view.sel()
        selection_region = select[0]
        selection_text = self.view.substr(selection_region)
        print(selection_text)

        # ASCII link for solved encoding problems —
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/40654295/5951529
        ascii_link = safe_url_string(
            u'http://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=' + (selection_text),
            encoding="UTF-8")
        print(ascii_link)
        # SERP DuckDuckGo
        serp = urllib.request.urlopen(ascii_link)
        # Reading SERP
        read_serp = serp.read()
        # BeautifulSoup — https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923803/5951529
        parsed = BeautifulSoup(read_serp, "lxml")
        # Parsed first link
        first_link = parsed.findAll(
            'div', {'class': re.compile('links_main*')})[0].a['href']
        # Remove DuckDuckGo specific characters —
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/3942100/5951529
        remove_duckduckgo_symbols = first_link.replace("/l/?kh=-1&uddg=", "")
        # Final link — https://stackoverflow.com/a/32451970/5951529
        final_link = (urllib.parse.unquote(remove_duckduckgo_symbols))
        markdown_link = '[' + selection_text + ']' + \
            '(' + final_link + ')'
        print(markdown_link)

        # Replace selected text to Markdown link
        self.view.replace(
            edit, selection_region, markdown_link)
```

---

### 4. Expected behavior

If user have installed Python and install packages

- `pip install beautifulsoup4`
- `pip install lxml`
- `pip install w3lib`

I want, that my plugin from 2.2 item successful work for user.

---

### 5. Actual behavior

If I save my plugin, I get stack trace:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sublime Text Build 3126 x64 For Debug\sublime_plugin.py", line 109, in reload_plugin
    m = importlib.import_module(modulename)
  File "./python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 868, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Sublime Text Build 3126 x64 For Debug\Data\Packages\Grace Splitter\kristi.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

---

### 6. Not helped

#### 1. Using global Python environment of computer

I don't find, how I can do it. Examples of questions, that I can find:

- [**How to include third party Python packages in Sublime Text 2 plugins**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15180537/5951529),
- [**Using paramiko library in ST2 plugins**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/using-paramiko-library-in-st2-plugins/8021?u=sasha_chernykh),
- [**Best practices for plugin-deployment and packaging**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/best-practices-for-plugin-deployment-and-packaging/11427?u=sasha_chernykh),
- [**How to import a package and call its global functions / to get their global variable values?**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-how-to-import-a-package-and-call-its-global-functions-to-get-their-global-variable-values/22809?u=sasha_chernykh)

#### 2. Using Sublime Text environment

I install

- [**sublime-beautifulsoup4**](https://github.com/jlegewie/sublime-beautifulsoup4),
- [**sublime-lxml**](https://github.com/eerohele/sublime-lxml),

I copy my `w3lib` directory from `C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages` to `Data\Packages` directory of Sublime Text.

I run in Sublime Text 3 console:

```
>>> window.run_command("kristinita_lucky_link")
```

I get stack trace:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sublime Text 3 x64\sublime_plugin.py", line 818, in run_
    return self.run(edit)
  File "D:\Sublime Text 3 x64\Data\Packages\KristinitaLuckyLink\KristinitaLuckyLink.py", line 32, in run
    parsed = BeautifulSoup(read_serp, "lxml")
  File "D:\Sublime Text 3 x64\Data\Packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

I don't find, how I can set `lxml`.

#### 3. Using variables in 2 files

For example I have `KristinitaLuckyLink.py` and `KrisDuckDuckGo.py` files in the same directory.

My `KristinitaLuckyLink.py` file:

```python
import re
import requests
import sublime_plugin
import subprocess
import sys
sys.path.append(
    'D:\Sublime Text 3 x64\Data\Packages\KristinitaLuckyLink\KrisDuckDuckGo.py')

from KrisDuckDuckGo import final_link
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class KristinitaLuckyLinkCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):
        # Get selection text
        print('KristinitaLuckyLink called')
        select = self.view.sel()
        selection_region = select[0]
        selection_text = self.view.substr(selection_region)
        print(selection_text)

        # Get terminal output — https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760517/5951529
        # Paths is correct
        result = subprocess.run(["C:\Python36\python.exe", "D:\Sublime Text 3 x64\Data\Packages\KristinitaLuckyLink\krisduckduckgo.py"],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        final_link = result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
        print(final_link)

        # Markdown link
        markdown_link = '[' + selection_text + ']' + \
            '(' + final_link + ')'
        print(markdown_link)

        # Replace selected text to Markdown link
        self.view.replace(
            edit, selection_region, markdown_link)
```

My `KrisDuckDuckGo.py` file:

```python
import urllib

import sys
sys.path.append(
    'D:\Sublime Text 3 x64\Data\Packages\KristinitaLuckyLink\KristinitaLuckyLink.py')

from w3lib.url import safe_url_string

from KristinitaLuckyLink import selection_text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# ASCII link for solved encoding problems —
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/40654295/5951529
ascii_link = safe_url_string(
    u'http://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=' + (selection_text),
    encoding="UTF-8")
print(ascii_link)
# SERP DuckDuckGo
serp = urllib.request.urlopen(ascii_link)
# Reading SERP
read_serp = serp.read()
# BeautifulSoup — https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923803/5951529
parsed = BeautifulSoup(read_serp, "lxml")
# Parsed first link
first_link = parsed.findAll(
    'div', {'class': re.compile('links_main*')})[0].a['href']
# Remove DuckDuckGo specific characters —
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/3942100/5951529
remove_duckduckgo_symbols = first_link.replace("/l/?kh=-1&uddg=", "")
# Final link — https://stackoverflow.com/a/32451970/5951529
final_link = (urllib.parse.unquote(remove_duckduckgo_symbols))
print(final_link)
```

I select any text → I print in Sublime Text console:

> window.run_command("kristinita_lucky_link")

I don't get output in Sublime Text console.

---

### 7. Environment

**Operating system and version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN
**Sublime Text:**
Build 3126
**Python:**
3.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, plugins can work with Python modules, that user install globally. You are not obligated introduce modules to your Sublime Text plugin.

## Problems

### 1. Python 3.3 compatibility

**For** begin of 2018:

**All global modules, that you use in your plugins, must be compatible with Python 3.3.**

#### 1.1. Argumentation

#### 1.1.1. Sublime Text sys.path order

For example, I add to `Default.sublime-package` archive file `0000.py`. Modules from `Default.sublime-package` are [**loaded first**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#merging-and-order-of-precedence) by Sublime Text start.

`0000.py` content:

```python
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\\Python36')
sys.path.append('C:\\Python36\\python36.zip')
sys.path.append('C:\\Python36\\DLLs')
sys.path.append('C:\\Python36\\lib')
sys.path.append('C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages')
```

Where paths — my global `sys.path`.

```python
>>> import sys; sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python36', 'C:\\Python36\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I restart Sublime Text → I see in console:

```python
DPI scale: 1
startup, version: 3143 windows x64 channel: stable
executable: /D/Sublime Text Build 3143 x64 For Debug/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /D/Kristinita
packages path: /D/Sublime Text Build 3143 x64 For Debug/Data/Packages
state path: /D/Sublime Text Build 3143 x64 For Debug/Data/Local
zip path: /D/Sublime Text Build 3143 x64 For Debug/Packages
zip path: /D/Sublime Text Build 3143 x64 For Debug/Data/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Anaconda", "Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 0.458819
startup time: 0.493818
first paint time: 0.506818
reloading plugin Default.0000
reloading plugin Default.auto_indent_tag
reloading plugin Default.block
# And so on
```

```python
>>> import sys; sys.path
['D:\\Sublime Text Build 3143 x64 For Debug', 'D:\\Sublime Text Build 3143 x64 For Debug\\python3.3.zip', 'D:\\Sublime Text Build 3143 x64 For Debug\\Data\\Lib\\python3.3', 'D:\\Sublime Text Build 3143 x64 For Debug\\Data\\Packages', 'C:\\Python36', 'C:\\Python36\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Paths from the internal environment are in front, that paths in global environment. I don't know, how I can change it.

#### 1.1.2. Python 3.6 module

For example, I want to use in my plugin [**Python Google Search API**](https://github.com/aviaryan/python-gsearch) PyPI module. It compatible with Python 3.6, but [**not compatible with Python 3.3**](https://github.com/aviaryan/python-gsearch/issues/3).

I inject file `0000.py` as in subsection above → I create plugin `SashaGSearch.py`, it content:

```python
import sublime_plugin

from gsearch.googlesearch import search


class GoogleSearchCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):

        results = search('kristinitaluckylife', num_results=1)
        r = results[0][1]
        print(r)
```

I restart Sublime Text → I get [**same traceback**](https://github.com/aviaryan/python-gsearch/issues/3#issue-287201481), as if `0000.py` not be implemented.

#### 1.2. Situation on begin of 2018

See Sublime Text forum discussions:

- [**Upgrade embedded Python to 3.6**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/upgrade-embedded-python-to-3-6/28883?u=sasha_chernykh),
- [**What is it modifying sys.path at startup?**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/what-is-it-modifying-sys-path-at-startup/32252/6?u=sasha_chernykh)

I hope, that in internal Sublime Text environment Python 3.3 will be replaced to 3.6 or next 3.7 version in the nearest future.

---

### 2. Environment variable

If you know, that possible don't add new environment variable, please, answer to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48276861/5951529).

#### 2.1. Plugin code

You need to create on your PC environment variable, where value — path to `site-packages` folder. For example, I named it `PYTHONPACKAGES`:

You need add to your code lines as in [**OdatNurd answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656754/5951529):

```python
# PYTHONPACKAGES path:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907053/5951529
# Disable duplicate paths:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656754/5951529
site_packages = (os.environ['PYTHONPACKAGES'])
if site_packages not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(site_packages)
```

#### 2.2. Activation instructions

Users of your plugin must also add environment variable `PYTHONPACKAGES` in operating system. In description of your package, you need add instructions, how do it.

- [**Example instruction from real Sublime Text plugin**](http://kristinita.ru/Programs/KristinitaLuckyLink#environment-variable)

---

### 3. Restart

**For** developing process:

**You may need to restart Sublime Text, if you change files in `site-packages` folder or subfolders.**

#### 3.1. Example

You install `examplesashamodule` from pip → you start Sublime Text → you import `examplesashamodule` to your plugin → you delete `examplesashamodule` from `site-packages` folder → plugin will work as `examplesashamodule` is still in the `site-packages` folder. [**AutomaticPackageReloader**](https://github.com/randy3k/AutomaticPackageReloader) package doesn't help in this case.

You restart Sublime Text → you get traceback in Sublime Text console, that `ImportError: No module named 'examplesashamodule'`.

Apparently, Sublime Text cache data from external modules in a session.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a Python version on your computer, that is not delivered with Sublime, you can make use of the following Sublime command:

`window.run_command("exec", {"shell_cmd" : '<your command here>'})`

This command allows  you to execute an application on your computer outside of Sublime. 
Just replace the `<your command here>` with the shell command you want to be executed.
The output will be returned in an output panel (terminal) in sublime. That output panel is different from the Sublime console.

You could put the path of the local Python you want to use in there and use the script (that requires the additional Python modules) as argument. 
For example:

`window.run_command("exec", {"shell_cmd" : 'C:\Python36\python.exe D:\Sublime Text 3 x64\Data\Packages\KristinitaLuckyLink\LuckyLink\LuckyLink.py'})`

You need to split your package into two files though. One file that describes your package and the commands needed inside of Sublime. The other file (which should be in a sub-directory of your package's directory -- so that is is not treaded as a plugin by Sublime) contains the rest of your code. 
The second file is where you import the Python modules that are not included in the Sublime internal Python. 
Also, you need to find a way to transfer the selection or string/url you want to work with to the second script.

You can check out how I did it in my Sublime package [PlotGraph](https://github.com/tibsel/PlotGraph/blob/master/plotgraph.py#L95).

Answer (score 3):

The error:

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

most likely comes because Sublime Text is finding the `lxml` installed as part of the global Python environment - which is compiled for a different version of Python than the one which ST uses - so it can't load it.

What we want is for ST to find the `sublime-lxml` dependency, which you linked to in your question. "Why is it finding the wrong one?", you might ask. It's hard to say for sure, but I think [OdatNurd's answer gives us some clues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656754/4473405) - the `sys.path` that ST sees for some reason includes all your global Python packages. By default, ST should only use the folder where it's executable resides and the Packages folders in the ST data directory. For example, on my system, executing `import sys; sys.path` in ST's console gives me:

```
[
 'C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3/python3.3.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Keith\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3\\Packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Keith\\AppData\\Roaming\\SUBLIM~1\\Packages\\lxml\\ST3_WI~2'
]
```

i.e. no `site-packages` folder.

The solution therefore is either:

a. You could try uninstalling the system-wide `lxml` package so that ST will only find the `sublime-lxml` dependency package, but really that is only a temporary measure. It would be better to:
b. Adjust the (order of items in the) path environment variable that ST is using. (i.e. remove all references to `site-packages`, or at least move them so that they come after the ST folders.)

Option B shouldn't affect any other ST plugins, because they would also suffer from the same problem. I suspect some other package changed the path ST is using, but it might not be easy to find out which one, without searching through them all. When build systems are used, the path which is used for those is quite different to the one that plugins use to load their modules, so build systems should also remain unaffected by this "fix".

Answer (score 2):

Python loads modules from locations it knows of via `sys.path`, and in Sublime Text 3 `sys.path` is pointed at a few locations only (e.g. the location of packages shipped with the Sublime executable, the location of user installed packages for the current user, etc).

In order to access a globally installed Python module from within a Sublime text plugin, you need to explicitly add its location to `sys.path` from within your plugin.

Assuming a Linux machine whose python packages are installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages` (modify that to wherever the appropriate path is for your Windows machine), an example of this would be as follows:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import sys

site_path="/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages"
if site_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(site_path)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        parser = BeautifulSoup('<a href="#">Link Text</a>', "html.parser")
        a = parser.find("a")
        text = a.contents[0]
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, text)
```

This specifically adds the path to`sys.path` if it is not already there, allowing the module to be imported and used.

Sublime includes its own distinct version of Python specifically to sandbox itself so that it is not at all reliant on any version of python or any python packages being installed on the computer that's being used to run it, which is why it doesn't do this for you by default.

Comment: OdatNurd, do you try to run real example from section 3.2? I try to use `site_path` like your example, but I get the same error like 6.2 section — `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?` Thanks.

Comment: I checked that the code I posted works and talks to a globally installed python library from within a Sublime Text plugin, so that proves that the technique works. I don't know enough about beautifulsoup to know why it would give that error, though.

Comment: `I checked that the code I posted works` — it don't worked for me (yes, I set `site_path = "C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages`). I get in Sublime Text console `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'`. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what that might be without the full context of the error.